# Query patient ID #s from an Excel 2007 list?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm using an Access Database that is designed relationally.  I have a list of patient IDs in an Excel spreadsheet that I imported and made into a table in Access named importedPatients.  There is a related table named Counties that is a one to many relationship for the main Patients table.  How can I use the patientIDs present in the importedPatients table to quickly query out information in the related Counties table?  Is there an idiomatic way to tackle this?

Comment: I don't think you provide enough information.  What is the relationship between importedPatients and Counties?  Do the importedPatients have a countyID?  Are the importedPatients duplicated in the mainPatients table? How are patients in the mainPatients table related to the County table?

Comment: importedPatients is a subset of patientIDs from a table called patients.  every patient is associated with one entry from the table Counties.  1 - many patients-Counties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you county information for each record in importedPatients:

```
SELECT counties.*
FROM counties INNER JOIN (importedpatients INNER JOIN patients ON
importedpatients.patientid = patients.patientID) ON 
counties.countyid = patients.countyid
```

Comment: came up with something like this when i went out to lunch :) thanks

Answer (score 2):

This diagram can give you an idea:

[image]

and here is SQL generated by the Designer:

```
SELECT importedPatients.ImportedPatientID, Patients.PatientName, Counties.County
FROM (Counties INNER JOIN Patients ON Counties.CountyID = Patients.CountyID)
INNER JOIN importedPatients ON Patients.PatientID = importedPatients.ImportedPatientID
```

Comment: +1 Your approach here is a neat way to avoid troubles with Access' strict requirements about the use of parentheses when joining more than 2 tables.  Might help to also show the SQL produced by this query.

Comment: Nice job, Igor.  This should be the accepted answer IMO.  But all I could do was vote.  :-)